# Properties Component

Tags: c#, components

What is the component that allows me to create a custom properties form? I mean, a component like this:

[image]

I'm trying to make an editor, so I need that component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done via quite a few things.  If you're working with the `PropertyGrid`, I recommend reading: [Getting the Most Out of the .NET Framework PropertyGrid Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx).

In particular, "[Providing a Custom UI for Your Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx#usingpropgrid_topic7)" describes the process of creating a custom [UITypeEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor.aspx).  In addition, it discusses `TypeConverter` and the attributes used by the `PropertyGrid` for handling custom type editing.

Comment: Thanks, seems like this is want I need.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to look into [`UITypeEditor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor%28VS.85%29.aspx) and the [`EditorAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorattribute.aspx). There are plenty of examples out there.